# Kubernetes: cannot see network policies created with calico

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
```

By using `kubectl get networkpolicy`, I can see only the policies created by `networking.k8s.io/v1` and not those created by `projectcalico.org/v3`. Any suggestion how to see the latter ones?

Comment: use `calicoctl`, eg `calicoctl get networkpolicy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kubectl get XXX` does not display all the resources in the cluster, in your case you cannot see CRD

- You can find your object with `kubectl get crds`
- Then `kubectl get <crd name> -A`

---

In your case it would be:

```bash
# Get all the CRD from the desired type
kubectl get projectcalico.org/v3 -A

# Now grab the desired name and do whatever you want with it
kubectl describe <CRD>/<resource name> -n <namespace>
```

---

[image]

[image]